# http pseudo streaming, how to get range from start param

Tags: node.js, video, video-streaming, mp4

We're doing HTTP pseudo streaming for MP4 files in nodejs.  For HTML5 this is pretty simple as it works with content-range header, however for flash, it's common practice to pass a `start` parameter to the request which contains the number of seconds to skip to.

Would anyone know what logic would convert seconds to bytes for a video and what else might be required for this? Any information in the right direction would be a huge help.

Thank you!